# How is a new tag added to many questions?

Tags: support, tags

I created a tag ["bri"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bri) on Politics SE since there are many questions there regarding BRI (i.e.  Belt and Road initiative).
A [search](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Belt%20and%20Road) found 63 questions mentioning it.

It isn't feasible for me to read every question, edit tags/the question and add the [bri] tag there.

How is a new tag added to many related questions, usually?

Comment: That seems like a very unclear tag. Feels like the tag should actually be "belt-and-road-initiative" ?

Comment: Related: [The system for adding a new tag to old questions is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379993/the-system-for-adding-a-new-tag-to-old-questions-is-broken)

Answer (score 7):

> It isn't feasible for me to read every question, edit tags/the question and add the [bri] tag there.

Yes, it is, just not in a single day - which is a good thing. Editing that number of questions would bump too many old questions to the site's homepage. Therefore, edits following [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)s are usually limited to 3-4 questions per day.

Adding new tags is not *that* urgent that it doesn't matter if it takes a couple of weeks or even months. It might be worth asking a question upfront on [the Politics' own Meta site](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/) to see whether the community agrees with you, and to invite others to help with the process. Personally, I don't like tags which are abbreviations (unless they're well-known); I'd rather see a tag spelled out as [belt-and-road-initiative](/questions/tagged/belt-and-road-initiative).